# SpringBoot - MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, rds

I can't connect to my RDS-mysql instance through Spring-boot.
I have set the values in the application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://my_rds_instance.rds.amazonaws.com:3306?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowMultiQueries=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = un
spring.datasource.password = pw
```

The weird thing is from that same machine, I'm able to connect to the RDS mysql server through the command prompt doing: `mysql -u root -h my_rds_instance..:3306`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: It throws this: 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user root@'....'  i'm using the same pw and username in the application.properties file as the cmd line prompt..

Comment: I added inbound rules for my ec2 instance on port 3306 and now it works lol